# How to use List view Builder without declaring height In showGeneralDialog in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I need to show general dialog, in dialog I am using list view builder, while I am using list view builder without declaring height of I am getting render box layout issue

Comment: Can you include minimal code-snippet that will reproduce the same error?

Comment: Just use ListView.builder with "shrinkWrap: true" inside widget like column or else it will take height automatic as per list

Answer (score 1):

`AlertDialog` provides scroll option, You can use `scrollable: true,`

```dart
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
    scrollable: true,
    content: Column(
      children: List.generate(223, (int index) {
        return ListTile(title: Text("$index"));
      }),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Wrap `List.generate` With `Flexible` Widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Expanded() widget which will allow you to give available space and try also giving shrinkWrap: true in ListView()

Comment: it will take full screen